# Read quicktime movie from servlet in a webpage?

Tags: java, html, servlets, video-streaming

I have a servlet that construct response to a media file request by reading the file from server:

```
 File uploadFile = new File("C:\\TEMP\\movie.mov");
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
```

Then write that stream to the response stream. My question is how do I play the media file in the webpage using embed or object tag to read the media stream from the response?

Here is my code in the servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getParameter("location"); 
    uploadFile(response); 
}

private void uploadFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    File transferFile = new File("C:/TEMP/captured.mov"); 
    FileInputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found"); 
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("in byes i s" + in.available());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    DataOutputStream responseStream = null;

    try {
        responseStream = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Io exception"); 
    }

    try {
        Util.copyStream(in, responseStream);
    } catch (CopyStreamException e) {
        System.out.println("copy Stream exception"); 
    }

    try {
        responseStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    try {
        responseStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And here is html page as Ryan suggested:

```
<embed SRC="http://localhost:7101/movies/transferservlet" 
    WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=196 AUTOPLAY=true CONTROLLER=true LOOP=false 
    PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, it is firing a `GET` request, but the servlet is listening on `POST` requests only. You need to do this task in the `doGet()` method rather than `doPost()`.

You also need to instruct the webbrowser what information exactly you're sending. This is to be done with the HTTP [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header. You can find [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) an overview of the most used content types (mime types). You can use [`HttpServletResponse#setContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) to set it. In case of Quicktime `.mov` files, the content type ought to be `video/quicktime`.

```
response.setContentType("video/quicktime");
```

Further, every media format has its own way of being embedded using the `<embed>` and/or the `<object>` element. You need to consult the documentation of the media format vendor for details how to use it. In case of Quicktime `.mov` files, you need to consult [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html). Carefully read this document. It is well written and it handles crossbrowser inconsitenties as well. You would likely prefer to [*Do It the Easy Way*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html) with help of a simple JavaScript to bridge crossbrowser inconsitenties transparently.

```html
<script src="AC_QuickTime.js" language="javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript">
    QT_WriteOBJECT('movies/filename.mov' , '320', '240' , '');
</script>
```

---

That said, the posted servlet code is honestly said terrible written. Apart from the `doPost()` incorrectly been used, the IO resource handling is incorrect, every line has its own try/catch, exceptions are been suppressed and poor information is written to stdout, `InputStream#available()` is been misunderstood, the `DataOutputStream` is been used for no clear reason, the `InputStream` is never been closed, etcetera. No, that is certainly not the way. Please consult the [basic Java IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [basic Java Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) tutorials to learn more about using them properly. Here's a slight rewrite how the servlet ought to look like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo(), "UTF-8");
    File file = new File("/path/to/all/movies", filename);

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/quicktime");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```

Map it in `web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>movieServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MovieServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>movieServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/movies/*</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
```

The aforeposted JavaScript example shows exactly how you should use it. Just use path `/movies` and append the filename thereafter like so `/movies/filename.mov`. The `request.getPathInfo()` will return `/filename.mov`.

Comment: Hi Balus. Thanks a lot for your feedback. My coding is still weak :)
I set the ContentType to video/quicktime and it does work. Great. There a lot to learn from you guys. I will try your example.

Comment: how many users are you expecting this servlet to concurrently service? Are you sure the I/O you've got going with creating the Fileinputstream is going to work for more than a few concurrent requests?

Comment: I must admit that I am new and amarteur to this. Do you have any good document on concurrency as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
<EMBED SRC="<your servlet hosting the movie>" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT = 196 AUTOPLAY=true CONTROLLER=true LOOP=false PLUGINSPAGE=http://www.apple.com/quicktime/">
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your help. But when I try it, there is error report that there is no plug in available for plugin application/octet-stream. ??

Comment: HI Ryan, I tried that but the browser reported missing plugin for application/octet-stream ??

Comment: try setting response.setContentType("video/quicktime") in your servlet just before obtaining the outputstream.. and a word of caution.. looking at your code I dont think this approach is going to scale for more than a few concurrent users.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I succeeded in it.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely supported way would be to embed a flash player (swf) and return a FLV file from your program.  Flash will automatically stream the flv file.

http://snipplr.com/view/288/flash-video-player-html-code/

Comment: Thanks Nick. But I need to play mov file as well.